# How do I create a Rails action for an Ajax request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, action, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a list of items in my shopping page, and each time an "add to cart" button is clicked, an AJAX request is fired off with only a product_id.

"*Add this item to the cart*" so to speak.

What does my Action have to look like in Rails for this scenario?

Comment: This can be answered with about 100 pages.  I'd need to assume too many details like:  are you using jQuery? do you want to return html or json?  At the end of the day ajax and non-ajax has no difference.  normally ajax has no layout (:layout => false) for html.  then there is a responds_to block for json.  or responds_with in the header

Comment: @drhenner: I'm **specifically** asking about the controller side, and what the action would look like. Just assume it receives a numerical ID. I didn't mention anything about the client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a great resource regarding [`respond_to`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods/respond_to) that you can read. That should point you in the right direction.

If you are using rails 3(.1?) you can set the `respond_to` in the beginning of your controller, and then simply using [`respond_with`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_with) to DRY up your code.